# How to remove stop words using string.replace()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file where I am counting the sum of lines, sum of characters and sum of words. How can I clean the data by removing stop words such as (the, for, a) using string.replace()

I have the codes below as of now.

Ex. if the text file contains the line:

```
"The only words to count are Apple and Grapes for this text"
```

It should output:

```
2 Apple
2 Grapes
1 words
1 only
1 text
```

And should not output words like:

- the
- to
- are
- for
- this

Below is the code I have as of now.

```
# Open the input file
fname = open('2013_honda_accord.txt', 'r').read()

# COUNT CHARACTERS
num_chars = len(fname)

# COUNT LINES 
num_lines = fname.count('\n')

#COUNT WORDS
fname = fname.lower() # convert the text to lower first
words = fname.split()
d = {}
for w in words:
    # if the word is repeated - start count
    if w in d:    
       d[w] += 1
    # if the word is only used once then give it a count of 1
    else:
       d[w] = 1

# Add the sum of all the repeated words 
num_words = sum(d[w] for w in d)

lst = [(d[w], w) for w in d]
# sort the list of words in alpha for the same count 
lst.sort()
# list word count from greatest to lowest (will also show the sort in reserve order Z-A)
lst.reverse()

# output the total number of characters
print('Your input file has characters = ' + str(num_chars))
# output the total number of lines
print('Your input file has num_lines = ' + str(num_lines))
# output the total number of words
print('Your input file has num_words = ' + str(num_words))

print('\n The 30 most frequent words are \n')

# print the number of words as a count from the text file with the sum of each word used within the text
i = 1
for count, word in lst[:10000]:
print('%2s.  %4s %s' % (i, count, word))
i += 1
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want these words filtered out before or after word counting?

Comment: I guess it would not really matter but I would prefer after the word count if possible.

Comment: Of course it would matter, removed words cannot be count :). I'll write an answer!

Comment: Yes you are write. And if the words are being removed, I guess there is no need for it to be counted. Thanks

Comment: @EbraHim See my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After opening and reading the file (`fname = open('2013_honda_accord.txt', 'r').read()`), you can place this code:

```
blacklist = ["the", "to", "are", "for", "this"]  # Blacklist of words to be filtered out
for word in blacklist:
    fname = fname.replace(word, "")

# The above causes multiple spaces in the text (e.g. '  Apple    Grapes  Apple')
while "  " in fname:
    fname = fname.replace("  ", " ")  # Replace double spaces by one while double spaces are in text
```

**Edit:**
To avoid problems with words containing the *unwanted words*, you may do it like this (assuming words are in sentence middle):

```
blacklist = ["the", "to", "are", "for", "this"]  # Blacklist of words to be filtered out
for word in blacklist:
    fname = fname.replace(" " + word + " ", " ")
# Or .'!? ect.
```

A check for double spaces is not required here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am encountering some problems. When using the blacklist to filter words, if the text file contains other words which contains the blacklisted words. it removes it from the actual word as well. for example. If i blacklist the word ["to", "are] and if I have a word [buttons, shares] the output removes the blacklisted words and gives [butns, shs]. How can I avoid that?

Comment: 2 things: 1) if you use the replace with list comprehension will it still work?   2)  why not call `.split()` method on `fname` then verify short string against short string? the way you are doing it will go through every char in sentence (even spaces") n times where n is the length of your blacklist, you are therefore looking at n*m complexity with a possibly huge m

Comment: @Mixone 2 Answers: 1) Why should we use list comprehensions here? We don't have to create a list. 2) Can you give a short example for this, so I can better understand it?

Comment: @linusg 1) I was just wondering if it would work in the sense of lauching a command via list comprehension more just to know

Comment: @linusg it won't remove stop word  how from ?   "how you doi'n?"

Comment: @ascii_walker yeah, there are probably even more cases where this would fail. My code isn’t meant to be ready for production but to give you an idea how this problem could be solved. You should try a Regex which would solve your problem easily ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily terminate those words by writing a simple function:

```
#This function drops the restricted words from a sentece.
#Input - sentence, list of restricted words (restricted list should be all lower case)
#Output - list of allowed words.
def restrict (sentence, restricted):
    return list(set([word for word in sentence.split() if word.lower() not in restricted]))
```

Then you can use this function whenever you want (before or after the word count).

for example:

```
restricted = ["the", "to", "are", "and", "for", "this"]
sentence = "The only words to count are Apple and Grapes for this text"
word_list = restrict(sentence, restricted)
print word_list
```

Would print:

```
["count", "Apple", "text", "only", "Grapes", "words"]
```

Of course you can add empty words removal (double spaces):

```
return list(set([word for word in sentence.split() if word.lower() not in restricted and len(word) > 0]))
```